# GET DataPart File Content Without Saving File

Tags: scala, playframework, multipartform-data, multifile-uploader

I am trying to get uploaded file's content (using POST) WITHOUT having to create/copy this file to the local directory. Is there any way it's possible in `scala`?
Here's my code:

```
def uploadSchema = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
request.body.file("source").map { sourceFile =>
  val filename = Paths.get(sourceFile.filename).getFileName
  sourceFile.ref.moveTo(Paths.get(s"/usr/local/polymer/schema/uploads/$filename"), replace = true)
  Ok(s"Uploaded successfully!"+sourceFile.)
}.getOrElse {
  Redirect(routes.NLPController.uploadSchema).flashing("error" -> "Missing file.")
}
```

What I want to do is, instead of doing

```
sourceFile.ref.moveTo(Paths.get(s"/usr/local/polymer/schema/uploads/$filename"), replace = true)
```

Do something like

```
val content : String = Source.fromFile(file).getLines.mkString
```

Here's my `API` from `routes` file

```
POST   /api/upload   controllers.NLPController.uploadSchema
```

Is it possible to this? If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that you want to do the following:

1. You want to upload something through your Play app to a machine.
2. You don't want to copy it to the machine's local directory.

The problem here is, where the file should go then? If I have an app in server, and I upload my file, with this method, the file will be **always** be on the server first. Because it should be copied somewhere before then you want to move it somewhere else (cloud, another backup server).

**What about reading the files content?**

This is another question, does not related to upload, rather than reading the files content, you can do this:

```
import scala.io.Source
val myFileContent = Source.fromFile("myFile.txt").getLines.mkString
```

**Update Note**

Ok, you are saying, in comments, that you have app A that you want to get the content of the file and then send it to the app B. Well why don't you do this:

1. **Route with Query String**: Have a route that gets the file's path as a query string:

   ```
   GET /file-content    controllers.file.readContent (path: String)
   ```

   Then you call the app like this:

   ```
   /file-content?path=whereever/i-want/myfile-be.txt
   ```
2. **Method to read the content and put it in a response**: Then within your `readContent` method you return the body of the file, to whomever who calls the app A:

   ```
   def readContent (filePath: String) = Action{
     implicit request => 
       Ok(Source.fromFile(filePath).getLines.mkString))
   }
   ```

**Update Note 2: Don't forget about security!**

The above solution works fine to read the data, and give it back. But, you should also take of security as well. You don't want to give the content of the file to anyone who calls that url. You could add token within the caller app, so the app who deals with the content of the data, first check if the user is authorized, and then check for the content of the file.

Comment: "You want to upload something through your Play app to a machine." Well, I don't want to copy it to a machine per se. Take it like two applications connecting, one application hits the upload `API` of my application, and I want to process that file and return a `string`. So what I am trying to say is, I just want the uploaded file's content in some kind of variable instead of saving it, and then reading it and then getting that content. Hope I am making sense